# create JUnit Report NOT on methods

Tags: java, junit, report

I am now writing a tester program. It read files and then do some testing. I can now output some message about the test cases into console. But I want to make it like JUnit Report(better in HTML), i.e. overview (with graph) of all files, clicking the file name to inspect detail message (and stack trace maybe).

I think JUnit are used in testing methods and then it can generate XML/HTML format file with some plugins(?). But seems this is not my case. So is it possible to do it? If not, any suggestions?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am annotating `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` before my test class. This give me a guided way to put different parameter for the same method. So that I can use it to validate different files and generate report.

and i find the example in this link is quite useful.

http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/23/how-to-write-parameterized-testcases-with-junit-4/